# Lookup a value from database and get the list of matching values to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to find the corresponding Disc Codes from a list and copy them in the DiscName column in the summary sheet. Some lab names will have more than one Disc codes so when I run the macro, it should bring up all the relevant Disc Codes matching with the Lab name to DiscName column.

Not sure if I can upload the image of the summary sheet but it looks like this.

```
Col 1                col 2     col 3
Lab name             Disc Name
(say abcd)           xxxx
                     yyyy
                     zzzz
                     pppp
```

and the list looks something like this.

```
Col 1          Col 2
Lab name       Disc name
abcd            xxxxx
abcd            yyyyy
abcd            zzzzz
abcd            ppppp
bcda            qqqqq
bcda            rrrrr
bcda            iiiii
bcda            jjjjj
bcda            kkkkk
```

I just re arranged the table so it looks more clearer.

I tried this code but I cannot get it to write the next Disc name in the next row after under Disc name in the summary sheet. It repeats the same Disc name as the first one. Ideally it should continue to fill in the Summary sheet with all the relevant Disc Names appearing agianst the Lab name in the list.

```
Sub Vlooker()

    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim fcomp
    For Each fcomp In Sheets("cont").Range("p3") ' range of Source Comparison

        FindString = fcomp
   
        
        With Sheets("list").Range("q2:q106") 'range of cells to search
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                            After:=.Cells(1), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            
            If Rng Is Nothing Then
           
                
                
            Else
            Do While fcomp = FindString
              fcomp.Offset(0, 1).Value = Rng.Offset(0, 1)
              fcomp.Offset(1, 1).Value = Rng.Offset(0, 1) 
              Loop

            End If
        End With
             
  Next fcomp
  
End Sub
```

This is what I want to happen real symple terms.

```
Go to List, Check A2. 
If list A2 matches with Summary A2 then 
go to summary b2
make summary b2 value = to list b2 value
then chekc next row in list
if found match with summary a2 then
go to summary, last actioned cell, go one row down and make value = to the value in column b in  list against the matching cell
Repeat this process till all matches found for summary a2.
Start this process when ever value of summay a2 changes.
```

Comment: I suspect you need to use VLOOKUP(), but your question isn't clear because the formatting didn't come through.  Put four spaces in front of each example row to allow the formatting to show as code, or else put a screenshot of your sheet.

Comment: @NYCdotNet I just edited my post as you suggested. Hope it is more clear now.. Thnks..

Comment: If you need to account for multiple matches, it might be best-served using the range `.Find` method in a loop. Or you could use the range `.AutoFilter` method on the list sheet, and then iterate over the visible cells (`SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`)? Or you could just build an array in memory and print/transpose that out to the worksheet?  There's several ways to approach this problem.  *What have you tried so far?*

Answer (score 0):

This function will do something similar to what you're asking for.  Place the code in a new module in the VBA editor.

Make sure your second tab is called "Mappings" (or change the code).  This tab should have two columns just as you identified in your question.

Then just set cell B2 to the formula =DisciplineLookup(B1) and you should see the looked-up data.  Note that you will also have to edit the formatting for column B to "Wrap Text" on the alignment tab.

I don't think this is exactly what you were looking for, but it may solve your problem.  If this doesn't work, you might want to investigate creating a new tab with a macro that clears it and outputs a report when run.

Note that you may have to hit CTRL+ALT+F9 to forcefully recalculate everything if you update the base data even if you have auto-calculations enabled.

```
Function DisciplineLookup(TheLabName As String) As String

    Dim objSheet As Worksheet, intUsedRows As Integer
    Set objSheet = Sheets("Mappings")
    intUsedRows = objSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    'Get all of the relevant data into a VBA array.
    Dim objData() As Variant
    objData = objSheet.Range("A2", "B" & CStr(intUsedRows)).Value
    Dim objDisciplines As New Collection


    'Find rows matching the passed parameter, and add them to a collection
    Dim intI As Integer
    For intI = 1 To intUsedRows - 1
        If objData(intI, 1) = TheLabName Then
            objDisciplines.Add objData(intI, 2)
        End If
    Next

    'Format the collection into a new concatenated string
    'Note this may be really slow if you have a lot of data
    ' If so, look into using an array and the JOIN function
    Dim strDisciplines As String, strDiscipline As Variant
    strDisciplines = ""
    For Each strDiscipline In objDisciplines
        strDisciplines = strDisciplines & CStr(strDiscipline) & vbCrLf
    Next

    'trim trailing CRLF
    If Len(strDisciplines) > 0 Then
        strDisciplines = Left(strDisciplines, Len(strDisciplines) - 2)
    End If

    DisciplineLookup = strDisciplines

End Function
```

Comment: @NYCdoNet Thanks Mate, just one problem, Where there are more than one disciplines, they all comes in one cell, is there a way to get them separated to fit one disc to one cell?

Comment: I suspected you might want that.  Your best bet may be to make a new tab called "report" and write a macro to clear it and copy all the data from the first two tabs in nested FOR loops breaking out all of the disciplines when rendering each lab.  The function above is a good starting point for the inner loop, but you'd return the collection of disciplines `objDisciplines` instead of returning a concatenated string.  Hope that helps.