# Search text in range, if matches, return match value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of street names and of addresses. Now I want to find whether in the Address column there is any value that matches the one in Street name, then return the street name.

[image]

Comment: If a cell contains whole adress as a string how can it be known which part of that string is street name if there aren't seperators or if there is another street names list.

Comment: street name is standard list as a source to compare.

Comment: I think my problems is similar as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937704/lookup-a-value-from-database-and-get-the-list-of-matching-values-to-another-shee?rq=1

Comment: Where the string to be looked for come from. From a textbox? 1)Find the cell which contains that string. You may use find function. 2) Then get the value and using a loop do the second part.

Comment: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Show what you've attempted to write and where your errors or struggles are. I'm sure someone will be happy to help you fix it, but this isn't a  code writing service - you're unlikely to get someone to write it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assume Adress column is `A` Street_name column is `C`. This code is not the most elegant but works.

```
Private Sub DoTheJob()
    Dim intRowStreetName As Integer
    Dim intRowAdress As Integer
    intRowStreetName = 1
    intRowAdress = 1
    strPartOfStreetName = "nguyen"
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Do While .Cells(intRowStreetName, 3).Value <> Empty
            intRowAdress = 1
            If InStr(1, .Cells(intRowStreetName, 3).Value, strPartOfStreetName, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                Do While .Cells(intRowAdress, 1).Value <> Empty
                    If InStr(1, .Cells(intRowAdress, 1).Value, .Cells(intRowStreetName, 3).Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                       .Cells(intRowAdress, 2).Value = .Cells(intRowStreetName, 3).Value
                    End If
                intRowAdress = intRowAdress + 1
                Loop
            End If
            intRowStreetName = intRowStreetName + 1
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks kitap mitap, it works like a charm, for me now, there is no need to use the strPartOfStreetName. Many thanks! I'm beginer of VBA, It's useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *Address* is in A1:

```
For AddressRow = FirstRow To LastRow
    address = Cells(AddressRow,1)
    For StreetRow = FirstRow To LastRow
        If "*" & Cells(StreetRow,3) & "*" Like address Then MsgBox Cells(StreetRow,3)
    Next
Next
```

I hope you can define the FirstRow, the LastRow and know where you want the output that right now goes to a messagebox.

Comment: I always mix them up, let me know if `address Like "*" & Cells(StreetRow,3) & "*"` works. The asterixes are important, they mean it's a substring. You can use the equivalent `InStr()` function.

Comment: The "*" by the way is a wildcard, means any character; I have successfully used it in SQL queries, Excel and Access VBA macros (decision trees to be exact).